# can i use a variable's value as the name of an object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several Dropdown lists that need to have the same data inserted into them, and I was wondering if I could make a function to fill in all this data and pass it a variable to use as the name of the object.

```
public void populateDDL(double MaxNumber, string DDLName)
{
    double currentNumber = 0
    while (currentNumber < MaxNumber)
    {
        thickness = currentNumber + .5;
        ListItem Gen1Item = new ListItem();
        Gen1Item.Text = currentNumber.ToString();
        Gen1Item.Value = currentNumber.ToString();
        DDLName.Items.Add(Gen1Item);
    }
}
```

The function would accept a max number that it would fill the DDL to in increments of .5, then use the string passed to it to indicate which DropDownList it should be filling.

Comment: Why don't you pass in a reference to the DDL instead of passing in a string?

Comment: primarily, because I didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: Code is compiled before you run it.  What would be the purpose of creating new variables whilst the program is running.  (I realise technically you can do this via reflection, but that's not the question).

Comment: Yes, you can pass any variable you like into a function, it doesn't matter what type of variable it is. You're not limited to simple types like string, int etc, any object can be passed. Usually that's something you learn quite early on when you learn .NET (or similar languages).

Comment: all of my learning .net and C# comes from running 15-year-old Visual Basic through an online vb->C# converter and googling things until it works. I'm just now starting to branch out and seriously create my own code instead of hacking at pre-generated code. Thanks for being understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in a reference to the actual `DropDownList` instead of passing in a `string`:

```
public void populateDDL(double MaxNumber, DropDownList dll)
{
    double currentNumber = 0
    while (currentNumber < MaxNumber)
    {
        thickness = currentNumber + .5;
        ListItem Gen1Item = new ListItem();
        Gen1Item.Text = currentNumber.ToString();
        Gen1Item.Value = currentNumber.ToString();
        ddl.Items.Add(Gen1Item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suprised it works... when does the loop end? Shouldn't `thickness = currentnumber + .5;` be something  like `currentnumber += .5;`?

Comment: you are correct! nice catch! I missed switching out that "thickness" for "currentNumber" when i was cleaning the code for display.

Comment: i missed something in your comment. by adding += instead of =, you will have the loop run once you hit your max number resulting in (for example) a MaxNumber of 12 and a max currentNumber of 12.5